# Remove some totals in power BI

Tags: sum, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm pretty new in Power BI, I have a table with 6 columns, the last row obviously is the total with the sum / mean of the rows. I just need to remove 3 of the 6 totals. I mean I want that there is a blank/empty string. How can I do that?

[image]

I want to remove the 3 values in the picture. I hope this is a easy task.
thank you

Comment: You can use function HASONEVALUE( columnName) with if.

if (HASONEVALUE('Table'[SomColumn],  'then your calculation',  BLANK() )

Comment: How can I mark this answer as solved?

Comment: I post this comment as an Answer, if you want you can click on the "confirmation checkmark" (leftside)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function HASONEVALUE( columnName) with if. if (HASONEVALUE('Table'[SomColumn], 'then your calculation', BLANK() )